# How should I approach patching a Plotly syntax error under Python2.6?

Tags: python, python-2.6, plotly

I am forced to use Python2.6 for a CGI project and am attempting to use Plotly to create histograms.

Here is the function that creates my histogram figure:

```
def get_histogram(self, dataset_uuid, target, title, xaxisTitle, yaxisTitle):
    max_threshold = self.get_max_threshold(dataset_uuid, target)

    thresholds = [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5]
    counts = []

    for i, percentage in enumerate(thresholds):

        # Query the database for all of the records with frequencies above the
        # threshold.
        result = (self.session.query(Mesh)
            .filter(Mesh.frequency >= percentage * max_threshold)
        )

        # Appends the fetched record count to the list of counts
        counts.append(result.count())

        # Change percentages from float to integer
        thresholds[i] = percentage * 100

    graph = go.Histogram(
        x = thresholds,
        y = counts,
        type='bar'
    )

    layout = go.Layout(
        title = title,
        xaxis = dict(
            title = xaxisTitle
        ),
        yaxis = dict(
            title = yaxisTitle
        )
    )

    data = [graph]
    figure = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)

    return json.dumps(figure, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
```

Under Python2.7 my script runs as expected, however, when I try 2.6 I receive the following syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.cgi", line 4, in <module>
    from viads import Application
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/viads/viads/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from application import Application
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/viads/viads/application.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mysqlDatabase import MysqlDatabase
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/viads/viads/mysqlDatabase.py", line 3, in <module>
    from database import Database
  File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/viads/viads/database.py", line 9, in <module>
    import plotly.plotly
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/plotly/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from plotly import (plotly, graph_objs, grid_objs, tools, utils, session,
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/plotly/plotly/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . plotly import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.py", line 114
    user_plot_options = {k: v for k, v in user_plot_options.items()
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Investigating `plotly.py` revealed the following list comprehension:

```
user_plot_options = {k: v for k, v in user_plot_options.items()             
                      if k in default_plot_options}
```

Which I believe is trying to convert list of doubles to a dictionary of Plotly configuration options.

Since this is a syntax error from within the Plotly source itself for Python2.6 should I patch this for my own project and consider contributing it back to Plotly?

P.S. I understand the downsides of using older versions of Python and of not using FCGI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing an older version of Plotly, specifically version 1.6.7 from https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases.

Comment: i installed the older version but it doesn't support plotly offline feature. do you figure out how to use the latest version ? thanks

Comment: Not with cPython 2, no. If you're locked into using Python 2 then perhaps a newer version of Plotly with the offline feature could be ported backwards;  Honestly though, a better option would be to do you all of your plotting using the Javascript version of Plotly to escape from the version issue.